# How can I search for bolded or underlined text?

Tags: man, less

How can I search for bolded or underlined text? This would often be useful to search for keywords, which are often highlighted as such. For example, in this excerpt from `bash(1)`:

[image]

I might want to search for `read` or `timeout`, but searching for only that will give me dozens of useless results which I will have to `n` past. There are some "tricks" you can use to reduce this (e.g. searching for `<Space>read<Space>` or `read \[`), but that doesn't always work for every manpage or keyword.

Note that I'm not particularly attached to `less` as such; using a different pager is fine. `less` just happens to be the default pager.

Comment: Use their escape code, Bold is 1, and 4 for underline.

Comment: However (nroff or [tg]roff ) may be store another way, find way of (nroff or [tg]roff ).

Comment: Use `info` instead of `man` and use the index. `i`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've never been able to use `info` without getting seriously lost all over the place. e.g. typing `info ls` and searching for `hello` brings me to ... I have no idea where ... but it's not the `ls` documentation ... Pressing Pageup a few times brings me to ... somewhere else ... but also not the `ls` documentation ... I find it seriously confusing :-/ But perhaps I need to re-investigate (it's been years since I seriously looked at `info`)

Comment: You could start with the tutorial. The index with completion is really a killer feature, especially for a manual the size of `bash`'s

Answer (score 5):

Use Vim as `MANPAGER`. With some creative use of [conceal](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#conceal) and [`iskeyword`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27), this can be done:

```
setlocal nowrap
setlocal conceallevel=3
setlocal concealcursor=nvic
exe "setlocal iskeyword+=\b,_"
syntax match BACKHIDE '.\b' conceal contained
syntax match BOLD '\(.\)\b\1' contains=BACKHIDE
syntax match Underlined '_\b.' contains=BACKHIDE
highlight BOLD cterm=bold
```

[image]

Since the Backspace, etc., are still there, a search for the word using `*` will only match similarly highlighted words:

[image]

Note how the bold `man` is found, but the normal `man` in the current line is not.

With [some more settings](http://murukesh.me/2015/08/28/vim-for-man.html) (shameless plug), Vim provides a comfortable pager for `man`, and a better one than `less`.

To get Vim to apply the relevant settings, here's what I do:

1. In a suitable place for environment variables, `MANPAGER='vim -'`.
2. In `~/.vim/vimrc`, have a minimum of:

   ```
   set nocompatible
   filetype plugin on
   syntax on

   if !empty($MAN_PN)
       autocmd StdinReadPost * set ft=man | file $MAN_PN
   endif
   ```

   For a command started by `man` using `MANPAGER`, the manpage name is provided in the `MAN_PN` environment variable. We can take advantage of this to detect when Vim is being used as `MANPAGER` and for finding out the manpage name.
3. In `~/.vim/ftplugin/man.vim`:

   ```
   setlocal nolist 
   setlocal buftype=nofile
   setlocal bufhidden=hide
   setlocal noswapfile

   setlocal readonly
   setlocal nomodifiable

   setlocal nowrap
   setlocal conceallevel=3
   exe "setlocal iskeyword+=\b,_"
   setlocal concealcursor=nvic

   nnoremap q :q!<CR>
   nnoremap <Space> <PageDown>
   ```

   The options create a read-only, unmodifiable, scratch buffer (see [How is a scratch buffer created? in Vim Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ)), disabling swap files. Then it applies the settings listed at the start of this post, and adds some mappings for convenience - `q` will close the current manpage, and <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> will move one page down, like in `less`.
4. In `~/.vim/after/syntax/man.vim`:

   ```
   syntax match BACKHIDE '.\b' conceal contained
   syntax match BOLD '\(.\)\b\1' contains=BACKHIDE
   syntax match Underlined '_\b.' contains=BACKHIDE
   highlight BOLD cterm=bold
   ```

   These are the syntax and highlighting commands from the start of the post.

With just these minimum settings:

[image]

Note how the top line is highlighted - Vim itself ships with some manpage syntax highlighting, which you can see if you removed the backspaces (using `col -b -x`, for example). However, you lose a lot more than you gain by that way, since Vim has no way to know everything that might have been underlined or bold.

My own personal settings use [the molokai colorscheme](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai), `set number`, the airline plugin, and a different highlighting for `BOLD`:

```
highlight link BOLD Constant
```

[image]

And because I have transparency enabled in the terminal settings (not visible in the screenshot), the colours are softer and more pleasing than seen here.

If you enable line numbers (`:set number`) like I have, set `MANWIDTH` to a value less than `COLUMNS` so that you won't have to scroll sideways to see the entire text. `MANWIDTH=75` works well for 80-column terminals. I use a drop-down terminal as wide as the screen (160-240 columns depending on the resolution), so a fixed `MANWIDTH=80` works fine for me.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot for the effort.  (shouldn't that be `~/.vim/after/syntax/man.vim` ?) I suppose one downside is that if you search for `/man`, you only see the unformatted ones. Maybe an addition could be a key binding to search for the text in the `col -b`-like processed version of the text.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, that should be `after/syntax/man.vim`, and, oddly, my settings do use just `\(.\)` without repetition. I'll correct both. `\b` didn't work with `iskeyword` the first time I tried it, I'll test that again when I get the chance. There are other things for which the presence of backspaces causes problems - Vim's manpage settings include a mapping to open the current word's manpages using Ctrl-], like with tag definitions.

Comment: `\(.+\)` might have been to cover for bold+underline.

Answer (score 4):

There's no clean way I know of.

You can turn off the special handling of backspaces which `less` uses to display underline/bold, and then use escaped backspaces to search for the string you want:

1. Open less (e.g. `man less`)
2. Turn off UNDERLINE-SPECIAL (type `-U<Enter>`)
3. Type in your search string, using `<C-v>` to escape the backspace characters.

For underlined text, for example, you could type

```
/_<C-v><C-h>l_<C-v><C-h>e_<C-v><C-h>s_<C-v><C-h>s<Enter>
```

...to search for the underlined word "less".

For bold text, you could type

```
/l<C-v><C-h>le<C-v><C-h>es<C-v><C-h>ss<C-v><C-h>s<Enter>
```

...to search for the bold word "less".

As I said, there's no **clean** way.

---

**EDIT:** As Stephane points out in the comments, you can use a dot (which matches any character) instead of a literal `<C-h>`, which makes typing it easier.

```
/l.le.es.ss.s
```

to search for bold, and

```
/_.l_.e_.s_.s
```

to search for underlined.

You still have to turn off UNDERLINE-SPECIAL first, which makes the underlined/bold text not very readable.

Comment: Or `/r.re.ea.ad.d` to search for **read** a bit more easily. Interestingly when you do -U again, **read** is still highlighted

Comment: See also `GROFF_SGR=1 man bash`, use `-R` to see the escape sequences if need be and search for `1mread` for **read**

Comment: I always assumed that `man` uses ANSI escape codes, but apparently not (`roff`/`man` seems to pre-date that). Meh.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, on GNU systems, it does when GROFF_SGR=1 is in the environment. The problem with ANSI escape codes is that pagers have to be configured to recognise them (like with `-R` for `less`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas another problem is that the codes aren't matched properly. The sequence could look like: `^[[1mfoo ^[[4m^[[22mbar^[[24m`, which doesn't cause problems for `less`, but it does cause problems if you try to process it elsewhere (in Vim, for example).

Answer (score 3):

If you can see it as bold or underlined, you probably cannot search for it, because what you see is *rendered*.

For instance, if the text comes from any manpage formatted, it is produced by interpreting overstruck characters as

- bold (when each character is overstruck by backspacing over it and repeating) or
- underlined (when each character is written over an underline character).

The [`less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html) pager FAQ comments that it *interprets* the bold/underline.  It uses terminal video attributes to show the actual bold/underline.

In the process of rendering, a typical pager such as `less` pretends that it only holds the *text* (the bold/underline parts are not text).

In a text-editor, you can search for the backspace patterns.  Perhaps some specific editor (such as emacs) has the ability to do this, i.e., search for text (while it is rendered as bold/underline) but taking the bold/underline into account as an attribute of the search.

Reading backspaces is less pleasant.  Here is the beginning of the manpage cited in the question:

```
       r^Hre^Hea^Had^Hd [-^H-e^Her^Hrs^Hs] [-^H-a^Ha _^Ha_^Hn_^Ha_^Hm_^He] [-^H>
       _^Hp_^Hr_^Ho_^Hm_^Hp_^Ht] [-^H-t^Ht _^Ht_^Hi_^Hm_^He_^Ho_^Hu_^Ht] [-^H-u>
              One  line  is  read  from  the  standard input, or from the file  
              descriptor _^Hf_^Hd supplied as an argument to the -^H-u^Hu optio>
              first word is assigned to the first _^Hn_^Ha_^Hm_^He, the second >
              second _^Hn_^Ha_^Hm_^He, and so on, with leftover words and their>
              ing  separators  assigned  to the last _^Hn_^Ha_^Hm_^He.  If ther>
              words read from the input stream than names, the remaining names
```

Answer (score 3):

`less -U` makes the text pretty illegible. An alternative could be to pre-process the text to use unicode combining characters to implement bold and underline. For instance using U+0332 for underline and bold represented as a double underline with U+0333.

You could create a `upager` script like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
ul=$'\u0332' bold=$'\u0333' bs=$'\b'
sed "s/\(.\)$bs\1/\1$bold/g;s/_$bs\(.\)/\1$ul/g" | less
```

Then:

```
export MANPAGER=upager
```

`man bash` would render as:

```
   r̳e̳a̳d̳  [-̳e̳r̳s̳]  [-̳a̳  a̲n̲a̲m̲e̲] [-̳d̳ d̲e̲l̲i̲m̲] [-̳i̳ t̲e̲x̲t̲] [-̳n̳ n̲c̲h̲a̲r̲s̲]
   [-̳N̳ n̲c̲h̲a̲r̲s̲] [-̳p̳ p̲r̲o̲m̲p̲t̲] [-̳t̳ t̲i̲m̲e̲o̲u̲t̲] [-̳u̳ f̲d̲] [n̲a̲m̲e̲ ...]
          One line is read from the standard input,  or  from
          the  file  descriptor f̲d̲ supplied as an argument to
```

And you could search for a bold or underline `read` with `/r.e.a.d` for instance.

Not all terminal emulators seem to render those combining characters correctly though. I found `konsole` gave the best results so far.

---

A different and maybe better approach that also works in `xterm` could be to keep the roff formatting but postfix every bold or underline character with an invisible character. That way you can search for a normal `read` with `/read` and a bold/underline `read` with `/r.e.a.d` like above while the formatting is unaffected.

Invisible characters like U+200B the zero-width space are rendered by `less` as `<U+200B>` so are not an option. A character that seems to work though is U+034F the [Combining Grapheme Joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Grapheme_Joiner). That one is a combining character and is invisible and generally has no effect at least on English text.

So you could make a `gcjpager` pager like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
cgj=$'\u34f' bs=$'\b'
sed "s/.$bs./&$cgj/g" | less
```

(and `export MANPAGER=/path/to/gcjpager`).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well in `xterm` but it's an interesting idea and I might be able to base something off of it... Thanks.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, yes, AFAICT (and Thomas would be able to confirm), xterm only supports combining characters by converting sequences with them to their combined form (like `e\u301` -> `\ue9`, which can be confusing btw as what you copy-paste is different from what was being output) so it only works for sequences that have a combined form so generally not for underline combining characters. Another approach could be to insert invisible characters and keep the roff formatting, I'll add an example.

Comment: short answer: yes, xterm converts, which affects copy/paste - see [patch #279](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_279).

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but to more easily find documentation in a large manual like `bash`'s, you could try these alternatives:

#### Using a different format like `info`

The `bash` manual like the manual of most GNU software is written in texinfo, from which several formats are derived (man, info, pdf, html...).

A man page is called a *page* for a reason. It's just one flat text file where the only structuring is done via font formatting (indentation, bold, underline, all-caps).

For a manual this size, you'd rather want a *book* than a *page*.

While `man` implements the *page* paradigm, info implements the *book* paradigm. It has concepts of chapter/sections, table of content, references and index, all of which searchable with completion.

In a book about bash, to learn about the `read` builtin, you'd look at the index. In `info`, you type `i`, and then enter `read` (completion available) which will bring you directly to the documentation of the `read` builtin (use `,` to jump to the next index entry that contains `read`). You can also start `info` as `info bash read`.

In a book, if you wanted to see the section about builtins, you'd check the index again, or look at the table of contents. Same in `info` with `i` and `g`.

### Search the web

HTML is another hypertext format (note that `info` predates the web and HTML) well fitted for larger manuals. Web browsers can usually only search in a single page at a time which makes it not as good as `info`, but if you're online, you can make use of search engines like duckduckgo or google to search manuals.

```
bash read builtin site:gnu.org
```

would likely take you to the section that contains the documentation for `read`. Or you can use the index: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Builtin-Index.html#Builtin-Index

### search man page based on other formatting

Instead of searching for bold/underline text which is not easy to do with current man pagers, you could also try:

- search for `read` at the beginning of the line: `/^\s*read`
- also as a whole word: `/^\s*read\>/`
- you can also use the fact that section headers are less indented, to get a form of table of contents.

  In the `most` pager, that can be done with `1:od` to hide text that is indented, `4:od` to hide text indented by at least 4 columns.

  With `less`, you can do the same with `&^\S` and `&^ {,3}\S`, which would show something like:

  ```
  [...]
  RESERVED WORDS
  SHELL GRAMMAR
     Simple Commands
     Pipelines
     Lists
     Compound Commands
     Coprocesses
     Shell Function Definitions
  COMMENTS
  QUOTING
  [...]
  ```

  and let you navigate more easily to a section of interest (and then just enter an empty `&` to see the full text again, or `:od` in `most`).

Comment: If I type `info bash` and then type `i`, then ´info´ is reporting that there are no indices.

Comment: @JohnGoofy, your system is probably missing the `info` documentation, so `info` shows you the dumb man page. If on Debian or derivative, try `sudo apt install bash-doc`

Comment: Yes! This works! Thank you. But im wondering: Shouldn't this be a part of standard installation?