# How to grep/sed/awk regex and color in man pages?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, colors, man

If I do `man bash | grep read -c` the output is `218`. But I want to search only for colored regex in man. I still haven't find an approach. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: I take it you’re carefully avoiding the hammer there @Stéphane ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt, yes, the other one is for `less`, this one for `grep`, so while some of the answers there apply here, not all do, and some man implementations stop outputting in colour when piped and there way be different approaches that one could use for `grep`

Answer (score 0):

With the `man` implementation from [man-db](http://man-db.nongnu.org/)

```
MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 man bash | grep -c $'r\bre\bea\bad\bd'
```

See

- [Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371062) for the background and
- [How can I search for bolded or underlined text?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271550) for more options.